# PayCards Android Dependencies Errors | Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I recently migrated to Android Studio 4.0 and made the decision to update all dependencies, including Gradle.

When I tried to compile the app, this error *[the image below]*  is shown.

This type of error usually happens when libraries are updated, so I decided to go back to a previous commit where I didn't make any modifications but I was surprised that the error was still there.

I proceeded to check some similar errors on the network and made several changes with my gradle and dependencies .. even i went back to the previous version of Android 3.5 but the error persists.

I don't understand what the error might be. This image shows the versions of Gradle that I am using and the error that is displayed, I think it has to do with POM parser.

```
   [Fatal Error ]Getting root element must be well-formed. error in android build
```

Does anyone knows what might be wrong?

There is also an error with some libraries i am using (for example: paycards). 
https://github.com/faceterteam/PayCards_Android
the error shown is:
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed (but its in spanish... why???)

[image: example of the failure]

Comment: Looks like the problem may actually be with your dependencies, not with gradle. Upgrading now resulted in building a new gradle cache with your dependencies, perhaps exposing the problem that was already there but you were protected from because of your gradle cache.)

Comment: This is a very weird issue, i have not updated this paycard dependency because its the latest from 2 years ago ultil  now . and.. if this were the case, i think .. i would be fixed with a previous commit right?

Answer (score 0):

Today is 4 jun 2020 and i've made some research. there is actually some people with this error so i found a temporal solution an the Github 'Open Issues' segment of the PayCards library.

This issue was opened 3 days ago so i think its a new issue with the library.

https://github.com/faceterteam/PayCards_Android/issues/49