# Getting root element must be well-formed. error in android build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build an android project and keep getting the below gradle build errors. 
While it works fine in another mac.

```
[Fatal Error] paycardsrecognizer-1.1.0.pom:2:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
 [Fatal Error] onfido-capture-sdk-5.0.0.pom:2:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
 [Fatal Error] rootbeer-0.0.7.pom:2:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
 [Fatal Error] onfido-capture-sdk-core-5.0.0.pom:2:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: I have the same issue, it was before Android studio 4.0 update.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181112/android-studio-4-0-gaddle-errors-could-not-resolve-all-task-dependencies-for-c

Comment: Error was because the paycards maven repository was down for a week returning a 404 http page. it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help. I already have this problem and I found this issue on Github opened 3 days ago (1 jun 2020).

There is a temporary solution. You may subscribe to this issue to know what happen in the future.

https://github.com/faceterteam/PayCards_Android/issues/49